# Using MP-AES, can I accurately say I've found a metal concentration on one wavelength and not another?

Tags: spectroscopy, metal

I've been given the opportunity to use an MP-AES for metal detection. I'm testing traces of metals in plants. The plant matter is digested so I have a liquid solution, I expect there to be a lot of matrix affects within this. 
I have tried to use a couple of wavelengths for each metal cadmium, arsenic and lead.

Arsenic has a lot of carry over, and may be sticking to the plasma?
I'm ignoring it for now.

What I want to understand is the different ppm readings for the wavelengths, when looking at cadmium and lead. The 'u' symbol means that the concentration is below the limit of detection, but on another wavelength there is some concentrations of metals that are detected.

Is it biased to only be using the data from the wavelengths where metal has been detected? Even then, can I say that this concentration would be the correct amount in the solution?
Should I be trialling other wavelengths?

I'm struggling with what to search for when looking into the literature for something like this.

[image: Detection wavelengths for heavy metals]

Comment: There are many details, but it is certainly true that, for a given element, some emission wavelengths are “more sensitive” than others. More accurately, some wavelengths (other things equal) can yield lower detection limits. With commercial systems, the manufacturer usually provides some general guidance regarding wavelength selection and how to deal with matrix effects, etc.

Comment: A fancy instrument isn't a panacea. You still have to consider background and matrix effects. Also the software which is being used to reduce the raw data can be problematic.